# Handling missing data in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm facing a ridiculous situation. To tackle missing data issue, I used this code:

```
fixed_data <- fetch_data[-which(! complete.cases(train_sample)),]
train_index <- sample(1:nrow(fixed_data), size = .7*nrow(fixed_data))
train_sample <- fixed_data[train_index, ]
test_sample <- fixed_data[-train_index,]
```

Then I check the rows of portioned data to make sure there's no missing value, but there's still missing value!

```
length(which(! complete.cases(fixed_data)))
```

Comment: Define "missing data", is it a blank, an NA, some other character string denoting missing? If they are NA, you can use `is.na()` to find the rows containing NA. Character NA strings would not be seen as missing by `complete.cases()` as far as I know. So that could be an issue.

Comment: Not issue related, but `-which(!...)` is very ugly. Much better just `which(...)`. You should provide your data, otherwise how can someone help?

Comment: I'm using the which to remove everything that it consider not complete, and after doing so, it still consider some other rows as incomplete. That's the problem!

Comment: Your first line of code is the problem.  You are performing complete cases on the train_sample and not the fetch_data.  Try this: fixed_data <- fetch_data[complete.cases(fetch_data),]

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the issue, I'm doing the negative twice and it's not working fine for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to

```
fixed_data <- fetch_data[which(complete.cases(fetch_data)),]
```

And it's working now. What a silly mistake!